# How to Save Date in Yii with Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, yii

How does one save the date in Yii with Oracle?

```
$trx->DATE_TRX=date('Y-m-d');
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: 
    SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1861
    OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
        (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:148).
    The SQL statement executed was: 
        INSERT INTO "TRX" ("IDMEMBER", "DATE_TRX") VALUES (:yp0, :yp1) RETURNING "ID" INTO :RETURN_ID
```

Comment: My temporary solution-
"select sysdate from dual;",
I get:
"09-APR-13",
I use in php:
"$trx->DATE_TRX =strtoupper(date('d-M-y'));"

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you're supplying a character literal as the date, in a format such as 'yyyy-mm-dd'. If so then you should explicitly convert that to a date as part of the insert statement ...

```
INSERT INTO "TRX" ("IDMEMBER", "DATE_TRX")
VALUES (:yp0, to_date(:yp1,'yyyy-mm-dd'))
RETURNING "ID" INTO :RETURN_ID
```